# Rails remote form succeeds, but no data is returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple remote form with one input and send button.
I created listener for ajax:success:

```
$ ->
  $form = $('#post-form')

  $form.on 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log e
    console.log data
    console.log status
    console.log xhr
```

And my controller:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = 3

    if @post.save
      render partial: 'posts/view', locals: { post: @post }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I see that request passes on backend and status 200 is returned:

```
Rendered posts/_view.html.erb (3.0ms) [cache miss]
Completed 200 OK in 480ms (Views: 466.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

But in devtools I see:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @DeepanshuGoyal Yeah, I stopped using rails.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the data after you create the post, but in order to receive the data that was sent to an action via *JSON*, you have to return *JSON* from that action, as follows:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.user_id = 3

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { render partial: 'posts/view', locals: { post: @post } }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created }
    else
     format.html { render :new } # assuming you have a view file named "views/posts/new.html.erb"
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This way you can handle the request if it's *JSON* and you can handle the request if it's just plain *HTML*.

Comment: This isn't answer to my question. I want to render html on backend and pass it to front irregardless of where request comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Quick TL;DR:

Assuming your above code, this is the json response you're looking for:

```
e.detail[0]
```

This vexed me a bit as well.  Interrogating the one object that came back lead me to my answer- the result body is available in the event that comes back.  My Rails app is not using jQuery, so the resultant event object is an `ajax:success` result.

The result has a field called `detail` which (in my case) contained three items: the data from the response body of the called request (which I believe is what you're looking for), the String `"OK"` and the `XMLHttpRequest` that made the call.

So, in your above `form.on` callback, if you interrogate `e.details[0]`, I think you'll find the json data (also, the other params in the callback are unnecessary).

My assumption is that somewhere along the line, the callback logic for remote calls was simplified to a single parameter containing all the code.  Looks like this happened when the removed the dependency to jQuery for UJS: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The technique I have used in the past is the replace a section of the DOM as part of the AJAX request, i.e.

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = 3)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

And in /views/posts/create.js.erb

```
$("#new_item").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'posts/view', locals: { post: @post } ) %>");
```

Take a look at [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy).

Comment: I would rather avoid this approach. Is passing rendered html from backend impossible? I don't want js to know how view is rendered nor I want to remember that I delegated it.

Comment: To my knowledge this is the preferred and elegant way to do what you describe.   This actually does pass rendered HTML from the server side, it just wraps it in a piece of Javascript that replaces the appropriate section of the page.  You need to do this one way or another if you don't want to reload the page.  Doing this on the front end using hand rolled JS would be messy, IMHO.

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX you can just do something like redirect_to @post to route back to the resource.